# Copying raster from Raster Catalog

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, copy, raster-catalog, storage

I have a Raster Catalog containing 4 File GeoDatabase Raster Datasets.

Each raster is about 150-250 GB. I want to convert these to rasters with .TIFF extension so I can publish it in a map service.

The .gdb however, that contains the rasters, are strangely enough around 65 MB.

How can this be? I have tried using Copy Raster tool, and also exported directly from TOC. Both of these are taking ages to even get started.

Answer (score 1):

The [different methods of storing rasters](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t0000000n000000) in ArcMap are a little confusing. If you have a Raster Catalog, the actual raster data may be stored in a different folder, not directly in the geodatabase.

> Raster datasets can be managed within or as links on file system

Given the *very* different file sizes in this case, this "link" storage is more likely.

More related to your end goal: I am not aware of any reason raster catalog contents can't be copied or exported. Since they're quite large, however, it will take a long time to complete... I usually just let jobs like that run overnight.

Additional note: You might be able to use the [Copy tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//001700000051000000) as well ([this Answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82444/copy-rasters-slow-increases-file-size) indicates it's faster than Copy Raster) but I have not used it, and don't know whether it will work with a raster catalog that is linking to data.